# What is the correct way to control when/if to show tooltip in mobile app using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am writing a mobile app and when the user sees some screens of the app for the first time, I would like to show a tooltip, explaining some of the functionality.

For instance, the user navigates to the profile page, and I show a tooltip on the add icon, saying something like "you can add a photo here".

Obviously I dont want to show this tooltip every time the user navigates to the profile page, so what is the correct way of doing so? Is it via redux? Keeping some state like "tooltipWasShown"?

Or should I write a custom hook? Something which checks if the tooltip was shown? (this should happen again via redux I guess)

I dont think it is a unique problem, but I couldn't find any blog posts/examples of what is the way to implement it. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Async Storage for the save data about tutorial, if user reload app redux will be empty. Or will add isFirstEnter field to user in DB and then check this field